# The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found when using URL Encoding in WSO2 DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am trying to call an operation on WSO2 DSS server, the following URL works fine:

https://localhost:9443/services/TestData/testOperation?text=Test

But this one doesn't:

https://localhost:9443/services/TestData/testOperation%3Ftext=Test

Is there an option to accept this kind of URL?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported.
'?' is  used to separate query parameters from the rest of the URL. When '?' is replaced with its URL encoded value, there will be no way to identify the existence of query parameters.